# React native navigation not initialized yet

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm learning react native but I'm having difficulty with navigation, it's returning the error that navigation has not been initialized yet.
I looked for some tutorials, I tried some other ways, I went to the react native navigation documentation and, incredible as it may seem, it's the same as in the documentation... not even the GPT chat haha ​​it didn't help me.

Can someone with experience in react native give me a light?

app.tsx:

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import StackNavigator from './app/index/navigator';

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppContainer />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

navigator.tsx?

```
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import Index from '.';
import AddNewGrocery from '../components/addNewGrocery'

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  home: { screen: Index, navigationOptions: { headerShown: false } },
  addNewGrocery: { screen: AddNewGrocery, navigationOptions: { headerShown: false } },
});

export default StackNavigator;
```

index.tsx:

```
const Index = () => {
  return (
      
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <Text style={styles.title}>Gestão de Compras</Text>

      <LastFiveGrocery />

      <MonthAverageSpend />

      <TotalSpend />

      <AddButton />

      <StatusBar
        translucent={false}
        backgroundColor={'rgba(43, 43, 43, 1)'}
        barStyle='light-content' />
    </View>
  );
}
```

AddButton.tsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const AddButton = () => {

  const navigation = useNavigation();

  const handleAddButtonPress = () => {
    navigation.navigate('addNewGrocery' as never);
  }

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.addButtonContainer} onPress={handleAddButtonPress}>
      <View style={styles.addButton}>
        <Ionicons name="ios-add" size={36} color="white" />
      </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

I already tried to use it this way:
AddButton:

```
  const { navigate } = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>();

  const handleAddButtonPress = () => {
    navigate('addNewGrocery');
  }
```

I've also tried using it this way:
navigator:

```
const StackNavigator = createAppContainer(createStackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Index },
  addNewGrocery: AddNewGrocery,
}));
```

app.tsx:

```
import StackNavigator from './app/index/navigator';

const App = () => {
  return (
      <StackNavigator />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using 2 different navigation library in simultaneously:

1. @react-navigation
2. react-navigation

Remove `react-navigation` and refactor the `App.js` file as below:

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

import StackNavigator from './app/index/navigator';



const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <StackNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App
```

`StackNavigator` should be implemented as per documentation -

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#api-definition